# I want to scale images on a two column gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a problem to scale the images in the gridview on screen size. When I use FIT_START, I get a big space under the image.

here is the code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);


            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);


            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.info, R.drawable.open,
            R.drawable.news, R.drawable.specials,
            R.drawable.maerkte, R.drawable.anfahrt,
            R.drawable.artikel, R.drawable.kontakt,

    };
}
```

and when i use this:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

I get an Error: Unfotunately the app has stopped

Thanks for helping

**EDIT: [here is an screen capture](http://winni-darks.com/Unbenannt8.PNG)**

Comment: a screen capture would clarify the issue

Comment: that's helpful. try setting LayoutParams for the imageviews. Also, i'm not sure what your gridview code looks like, but you may be interested in setStrechMode and setVerticalSpacing

Comment: thank you verry much! did you have an idea how i can linking the gridview to different activitys?